# Iteratively generating power sets with c++

Tags: c++, iteration, subset

I'm trying to iteratively generate the power sets by trying to access the previous elements in my 2D vector.

```
    void sets(int a[] , int s )
    {
    int s_size = (2,s);
    vector<vector<int> > vecs(s_size ,vector<int>(s*10));
    //v.reserve(s_size);
    vecs[0][0] =-1 ;
    vecs[0].shrink_to_fit();

    int slot_no =1;

    for(int mainIterator = 0 ; mainIterator < s ; 
    mainIterator ++)
    {
        int current =slot_no ;
        for( int prevslot= 0 ; prevslot <current ;  
    prevslot++ )
        {
            int slot_traverse = 0 ;
            while(true)
            {

            if(vecs[prevslot][slot_traverse]==-1) break;

            vecs[slot_no].push_back(vecs[prevslot] 
            [slot_traverse]);

            slot_traverse++;
            }

            vecs[slot_no].push_back(a[mainIterator]);
            slot_traverse++;
            vecs[slot_no].push_back(-1) ;
            vecs[slot_no].shrink_to_fit();
            slot_no++;


        }
    }

    vecs.shrink_to_fit();
}
```

However, due to some reason the programs crash.

The -1 represents the end of a particular slot row:

[image: A horrendous attempt to convey the message]

Comment: where does the debugger say it's crashing?  also, you need to post a [mcve]

Comment: Can you explain what the "int s_size = (2, s);" line does?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free debugging service, and you should show your attempts at debugging the code with a debugger or other simpler methods such as debug print statements. You can also test each part of the code separately to figure out exactly which part of the code is causing the problem, and make a [mcve]. This won't be the only time you end up with a bug in your code, and learning to debug your programs will help you much more than having someone find the bug for you. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: @PlinyTheElder thats the size of the power set.

Comment: and thank you guys for the feed back. @f

Comment: and thank you guys for the feed back. @FeiXiang  I'm sorry for the poor translation of my bug. The error was not setting pow(2,n).